# Run .net console application with Selenium Webdriver inside Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile

I would like to run Selenium Webdriver inside a docker container and consume it within a .net console app with C#

My Docker file looks like this;

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Bot/Bot.csproj", "Bot/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Bot/Bot.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Bot"
RUN dotnet build "Bot.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Bot.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Bot.dll"]
```

And my Console app Program.cs is this;

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
Console.ReadLine();
```

The app is .net 6.0 and I am running Linux containers. I don't know if its relevent in any way but I intend to run this container on my Raspberry Pi.

Currently when I run this container I get the following exception when trying to instantiate  ChromeDriver;

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service
> on http://localhost:43407/'

I'm assuming the issue is that my container does not have Chrome installed on it but have no idea how to get this added (nor am I certain that this is the only issue I have).

I have added Selenium.Support and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver Nuget packages too.
I have copied chromedriver into my bin/Debug/net6.0 folder.

What do I need to do to get WebDriver running in a container?

Comment: did you try adding headless options, like `chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");` ? the reason being you are inside a docker and don't have any display showing.

Comment: @CharlesHan thanks but I tried that, still had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Chrome inside your container app.
This is docker file part which worked for me:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

RUN apt-get update; apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libglib2.0-0 libxi6 libnss3
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
```